# Remover linha de um array

Tags: c#, array

Como faço para remover a linha sem ficar espaço em branco?

```
N7 G90
N8 G26 RA 10.840
N9 G54 G92 X115.00 Y25.00

N11 C5
N12 D14
N13 G42 G01 X76.3276 Y-19.86
```

Tendo que ficar assim:

```
N7 G90
N8 G26 RA 10.840
N9 G54 G92 X115.00 Y25.00
N11 C5
N12 D14
N13 G42 G01 X76.3276 Y-19.86
```

Meu código por enquanto está assim:

```
//Remove Line Condition
if (_OS.Contains("M31"))
{
    _OS = _OS.Remove(0);
}
```

Comment: Isso seria um arquivo que você carrega,?

Comment: exato.. Virgilio, eu carrego ele, manipulo em uma array!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma outra alternativa, além da [opção postada pelo Virgilio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/159280/6454), se você for lidar com um arquivo pesado, é fazer a leitura de linha por linha do arquivo, nesse processo você pode pular linhas que não satisfaçam uma determinada condição, por exemplo, use [`String.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) para verificar se a linha está vazia:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
//....

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> linhas = new List<string>();

    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("foo.txt"))
    {
        string linha;
        while ((linha = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linha)) // Aqui você pode incluir mais condições com ||
            {
                continue;
            }
            linhas.Add(linha);
        }
    }

    // Use "linhas" aqui...
}
```

Uma segunda alternativa, se você estiver usando [listas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), é o método [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
List<string> linhas = new List<string>();
// Inserindo valores na lista...

linhas.RemoveAll(linha => string.IsNullOrEmpty(linha));
```

Comment: tentei todos os modos.. e o seu deu certo aqui, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Poderia utilizar [`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) para ler todas as linhas do arquivo e excluir aquelas que estão em branco com [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb397906.aspx) (`[Where](c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c))`):

```
string[] arquivo = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("arquivo.txt")
                .Where(c => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(c)).ToArray();

System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("arquivo.txt", arquivo);
```

Se quiser criar o arquivo, faça com [`System.IO.File.WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx), sendo que nesse exemplo, o arquivo foi reescrito. Pode sem problemas escolher outro nome e ficar com o original e a alteração.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar uma expressão lambda pra fazer isso

```
strArray = strArray.Where( x=>!x.Contains("M31")).ToArray();
```

Ele vai pegar o seu `array`, ver qual dos itens não contem a *string* "M31" e montar um novo `array` com a saída, removendo qualquer chave vazia.